# Could you use the Barnes-Hut algorithm iteratively-- with multiple center quadrants?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, simulations, many-body, algorithms

I was wondering if you could use [Barnes-Hut simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes-Hut_simulation) beyond what it was originally intended to be. For many Barnes-Hut algorithms, the forces are only considered for a single quadrant, the centroid, or the stellar body. Then, the algorithm branches out from there, affecting areas of influence and quadrants recursively. For instance:

[image]

Seems like the above Barnes-Hut algorithm was based on the central body from the animation.

**My Question:**

Would performing Barnes-Hut iteratively across all bodies, treating each body in-turn as the centroid, result in an accurate representation of an n-body problem where the sum force of gravity of all bodies is considered? Or am I misunderstanding exactly what the Barnes-Hut algorithm is?

---

If I'm misunderstanding the algorithm, can somebody re-explain exactly how this algorithm works? For anyone who understands programming to some degree, could anyone look at this project and tell me [if I'm missing something huge here? It's a Java GitHub implementation of the Barnes-Hut algorithm](https://github.com/carusocomputing/Barnes-Hut-Rewrite), but I've iterated it across all bodies (which may be incredibly stupid). Also-- yes, I know that's not how time works. Note: Credit due to original professor, as noted on GitHub.

Also, for those who aren't tech-savvy, can you look at this GIF and see anything inherently wrong? Red is less mass, white is more mass; yellow are two or more collided masses. Once the third yellow dot (combined mass) appears, things get interesting. I can't tell if interesting good, or interesting... bad.

[image]

Comment: Here's 1000 particles over 1000 steps: https://i.imgur.com/SwPbG4j.mp4

Comment: If you're iterating over all bodies, aren't you just doing standard inverse square law in all bodies? In which case, you've just undone the purpose of BH method??

Comment: @KyleKanos would it not be doing the inverse square law from a different starting point of reference though? I could be absolutely wrong in every respect.

Comment: The whole point of BH is to reduce the workload needed in solving $a_i\sim\sum_j 1/\vert r_i-r_j\vert^2$ by treating a bunch of particles as a cluster so that further objects from the cluster only feel the center-of-mass effects. If you start wanting to iterate over *more* of the particles, then you're undoing the whole point of BH approximation.

Comment: That is to say, the BH makes solving the acceleration $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$, so increasing $n$ (which is what you want to do) will make it *slower*. If you do BH on all particles, then you're back to $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ algorithm which is what BH was designed to avoid.

Comment: @KyleKanos I understand the time complexity is literally undone, my main question is whether or not the resultant physics would be accurate or not for an n-body problem. Not too concerned about time complexity. A big part about the algorithm aside from time complexity as I understood it was the ability to generalize long-distance and short-distance interactions in a large model. Also, I think it would be `O(n^2log(n))` as well-- right? `O(n)` x `O(nlog(n))`?

Comment: @KyleKanos I mostly am asking because for clustered map-reduce algorithms or multi-threaded applications an upper bounded n can act like `O(nlog(n))` because the tasks for each body can run in parallel. Of course this has an upper limit to how high `n` can go dependent on architecture. I was simply considered if the physics and logic of particle interaction was still sound given the iterative method.

Comment: Yes, the resulting physics would be accurate because you're doing sum of the forces still. It'd just be incredibly slower and not worth the effort to do it that way, even when parallelized.

Comment: @KyleKanos doesn't change any of the interactions even slightly? It seems to have results that are, over time, much less stable due to how the acceleration is calculated upon each body, in terms of their positions. You're saying I'd likely be better using an ODE solver for large values of `N` and solve the actual n-body problems-- in terms of time complexity and accuracy? I'd be remiss if I didn't ask you for alternative algorithms you know of, you seem to be fairly well informed, and this is the first physics algorithm I've honestly messed with in any capacity. Thanks for taking your time :).

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonably well known that at large enough distances, the force between a cluster of objects and another object is essentially equivalent to force between the center-of-mass of the cluster and the other object:
$$
F_i\sim\sum_j\frac{m_im_j}{\vert r_i-r_j\vert^2}\simeq \frac{m_im_\text{tot}}{\vert r_i-r_\text{com}\vert^2}
$$
where $m_\text{tot}=\sum_jm_j$ and $r_\text{com}$ is the center of mass of the $j$ particles.

The Barnes-Hut algorithm applies this to $n$-body simulations by breaking the domain into reasonably sized clusters and thereby reducing the number of effective bodies to iterate over, rather than summing over $n$ particles $n-1$ times. From what I can see/tell, the $n$-body simulations using the BH algorithm are fairly accurate, though there are better algorithms in terms of speed (e.g., [*fast multipole method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method) or other hybrid schemes).

> Would performing Barnes-Hut iteratively across all bodies, treating each body in-turn as the centroid, result in an accurate representation of an n-body problem where the sum force of gravity of all bodies is considered? Or am I misunderstanding exactly what the Barnes-Hut algorithm is?

Your proposal is essentially wanting to revert back to the summation of $n$ particles $n-1$ times, which would be equivalent to not at all using BH. It'll be accurate, though probably not much more accurate than BH, and it most certainly would be really slow.

So by questioning whether one can iteratively apply BH to all bodies, I suspect that you *are* misunderstanding the BH algorithm. The whole point of it is to reduce the workload required in finding the forces on the particles at each time step. You *don't* really want to increase the number of clusters, you want that minimized because doing an $\mathcal{O}\left(n^2\right)$ update *each* time step is really, really slow.